# JIRA query that returns all Epics that contain an issue that is assigned to me

Tags: jira, jql

Is there a way in JQL or with ScriptRunner to get all Epics that contain an issue that is assigned to the current user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires Scriptrunner (We have the most recent version of Scriptrunner, and believe that this query works out of the box even with the older free version.)

To return a list of all Epics which have an issue which is blocked within it you should be able to use

Issuefunction in linkedIssuesOf("status = blocked", "has Epic")

I have added this to some of our Kanban board and used it to change the color of the card where there is a blocked issue in the Epic (even where the epic itself is still has a status of in progress)

Comment: I'm quite surprised that this worked since when I tried it without "has Epic" I got all the linked issues without Epics... I wouldn't expect that adding "has Epic" will also change the definition of the result to include Epics...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with:

```
issueFunction IN epicsOf("assignee = currentUser()")
```

This selects all tickets that are epics of any ticket assigned to the current user.  You might want to add additional criteria such as `AND status != Done` to avoid getting a bunch of historical epics included as well.

It looks like this needs the ScriptRunner plugin.  The functions are documented [on their web page](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html#_issue_links).